# How to get lookup field text column to display as an image in a view?

Tags: jquery, list-view, lookup-column

Wonder if anyone can help. I want to add a category choice field to a SP2010 Announcements list. The category choice is a lookup field to another list. The other list contains the categories and a text field with the URL to the relevant category image. The idea is that users adding news items can choose a category and an image will automatically be added to the view (since users never really get their head around first uploading images then getting the URL then pasting it elsewhere etc).

I can get the lookup category to bring the text across but I cant find a way to format it as an image. I tried making the text URL into an actual hyperlink but then it doesn't show up as an option in the lookup choices.

Does anyone know a way of achieving what I am aiming for here? jQuery perhaps? All suggestions welcome,

Paul